# Calling git pull for a GitLab repository hangs forever

Tags: php, git, gitlab

I use PHP to call `git pull`

```
<?php
    $pdir=chdir('c:\repos\test');
    echo `git pull -v`;
    chdir($pdir); 
?>
```

When I do this for a GitHub repository is works perfectly every time.  However, when I do this on a GitLab repository it hangs forever.

My GitLab repo is self signed so I have exported the cert and added it to .git/config

```
[http]
    sslCAInfo =  C:/mycerts/gitselfsigned.crt
[credential]
    helper = wincred
```

Any help, hints, insights, or things to try would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what is output of git pull ? if you think problem with cert you can try use git config --local http.sslVerify false for git